# Java JFrame setSize doesn`t work properly

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am making a JFrame with the size of 500x500 pixels.
I make a blue background and add a red square in the right-bottom corner from (490,490) to (500,500).

Image: [image: http://imageshack.com/a/img913/7936/7ZdxvR.png]

I don't see the red square on the screen.
I switched the frame from not resizable to resizable and if I make the window larger the red dot is there.
Is the frame size the same as application's window size?
How can I make the application's window to be the exactly 500x500?

Comment: Post some code please

Comment: The frame size of 500x500 is the size of the whole frame including the window border. Your content pane (the blue one) will be smaller in this case.

Comment: Generally, you don't set the size of the JFrame.  You have no idea how high the title bar is on Windows, on Linux, or on OSX.  You can set the size of the drawing panel.  If you need a 500 x 500 drawing area, you create a 500 x 500 drawing area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frame is the size of the entire window, including the title bar required by the OS. When drawing things in the `JPanel` in the `JFrame`, the (0, 0) coordinate is in the top left corner if the `JPanel`, which begins just below the title bar. It sounds like your title bar is taller than 10 pixels, so 490 as a y component is actually off the window, since the visible height of the `JPanel` is `windowHeight - titleBarHeight`.

Comment: how to get the titleBarHeight and leftBarWidth?

Comment: @RazvanTurtu http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getInsets%28%29

Comment: @RazvanTurtu If you just want to get the size of the panel you draw on you can just do frame.getContentPane().getHeight() or getWidth().

Comment: If any question or answer helps you, click the up arrow, and if you are the asker, make it the answer to your question.

Comment: @RazvanTurtu You don't (or shouldn't) try to get the frame's insets, instead, you should allow the frame to use the appropriate sizing hints from the content and simply call `pack` on the frame, which will "pack" the window around the content

Comment: @Aderis This identifies the cause of the problem, but doesn't provide a (suitable) solution to the problem.

Comment: I'm not saying my answer is helping or is the best. I'm just making a general statement since none of the answers were given a +1 or marked as the answer when I made my last comment, and the asker is a new user.

Answer (score 1):

Your content pane should override the getPreferredSize() method, returning a Dimension object with width and height of 500 pixels:

```
public class MyContentPane extends JPanel {
    private Dimension dimension;

    public MyContentPane() {
        this.dimension = new Dimension(500, 500);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return this.dimension;
    }
}

// How to use your new class
SwingUtils.invokeLater(() -> {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title");
    frame.setContentPane(new MyContentPane());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
});
```

The size of your JFrame will be calculated by Swing by taking in consideration the preferred size of the components inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Should user the following

```
@Override
PreferedSize()
```

Remember preferedSize method is method of the super class JFrame.

Comment: That should `getPreferredSize` ;)

Answer (score 0):

this may be useful for you?

```
        JPanel aa = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        aa.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        aa.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(490,490));
        aa.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
```