# Different Output for Exactly Same Code Using Java Swing and AWT

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, awt

I am a newbie in swing and awt. I was implementing Huffman Tree in GUI. But in the code I written the output is very strange in Ubuntu(JAVA 8). Sometimes it prints the tree (haphazardly though) sometimes the window remains blank. The function `paintComponent` is being called for different times for different run. The code is same, no user input but for different run the result is different. Please run the code for at least 5 times to see what I said. Can anyone help me to get out of this problem?
N.B. You can directly jump to the `Huffman` class.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Queue;

class Node implements Comparable<Node> {
    private  char ch;
    private  int freq;
    private  Node left, right;
    private int x,y ;

    Node(char ch, int freq, Node l, Node r) {
        this.ch = ch;
        this.freq = freq;
        left = l;
        right = r;
    }

    public boolean isLeaf(){
        return (left == null) && (right == null);
    }

    public int compareTo(Node that) {
        return Integer.compare(this.freq,that.freq);
    }

    public Node getLeft(){
        return left;
    }

    public Node getRight(){
        return right;
    }

    public int getFreq(){
        return freq;
    }

    public char getCharacter(){
        return ch;
    }

    public void setPosition(int ht, int wd){
        x=wd; y=ht;
    }

    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }

    public int getY(){
        return y;
    }

    public String getString(){
        if(isLeaf()) return new String((Integer.toString(freq) + ' ' + ch));
        else return new String(Integer.toString(freq));
    }
}

public class Huffman extends JPanel{
    int height=0;
    String str;
    int[] freq = new int[256];
    Node root;
    Queue<Node> q = new LinkedList<Node>();

    static final private int LEFT = 5;
    static final private int RIGHT = 1300;
    static final private int TOP = 5;
    static final private int BOTTOM = 700;
    static final private int RADIUS = 15;

    public Huffman(){
        getStr();
        setFrequency();
        buildTree();
    }

    public void getStr(){
        //Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        //str = sc.nextLine();
        str = new String("What is happening?");
    }

    public void setFrequency(){
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++) freq[str.charAt(i)]++;
    }

    public void buildTree(){
        PriorityQueue<Node> PQueue = new PriorityQueue<Node>();
        for(int i=0;i<256;i++){
            if(freq[i]!=0){
                PQueue.add(new Node((char)i, freq[i], null, null));
            }
        }

        while(PQueue.size()>1){
            Node left, right;
            left = PQueue.poll();
            right = PQueue.poll();
            PQueue.add(new Node('\0',left.getFreq()+right.getFreq(),left,right));
            q.add(left);
            q.add(right);
        }
        root = PQueue.poll();
        q.add(root);
        setCoOrdinates(root,1,1);
    }

    public void setCoOrdinates(Node node, int wd, int ht){
        if(node == null) return;
        height = Math.max(height,ht);
        node.setPosition(wd,ht);
        setCoOrdinates(node.getLeft(),2*wd-1,ht+1);
        setCoOrdinates(node.getRight(),2*wd,ht+1);
    }

    public int getGraphicsX(int x, int y){
        return ((RIGHT-LEFT)/((int)Math.pow(2,y-1)+1))*x + LEFT;
    }

    public int getGraphicsY(int x, int y){
        return ((BOTTOM-TOP)/(height+1))*y + TOP;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        //this '*' is printing for multiple times
        System.out.println("*");

        while(q.isEmpty()==false){

            Node node = q.poll();

            int x = getGraphicsX(node.getX(),node.getY()), y = getGraphicsY(node.getX(),node.getY());

            String str = node.getString();

            g.drawOval(x-RADIUS,y-RADIUS,2*RADIUS,2*RADIUS);
            g.drawString(str,x,y+(RADIUS/2));

            if(node.isLeaf()==false){
                int leftX,leftY,rightX,rightY;

                leftX = getGraphicsX(node.getLeft().getX(), node.getLeft().getY());
                leftY = getGraphicsY(node.getLeft().getX(), node.getLeft().getY());

                rightX = getGraphicsX(node.getRight().getX(), node.getRight().getY());
                rightY = getGraphicsY(node.getRight().getX(), node.getRight().getY());

                g.drawLine(x, y+RADIUS, leftX, leftY-RADIUS);
                g.drawLine(x, y+RADIUS, rightX, rightY-RADIUS);

            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.setSize(RIGHT,BOTTOM);
        Huffman h = new Huffman();

        jFrame.add(h);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    ...
    while(q.isEmpty()==false){

        Node node = q.poll();
```

The problem is that you're modifying the queue inside `paintComponent`. The UI system can call `paintComponent` any time that it wants to, for example dragging another window over the panel will cause repaints.

`paintComponent` should therefore be stateless and not modify the queue.

If your use of `poll` is absolutely necessary, one simple solution is to copy the queue:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    Queue<Node> q = new LinkedList<>(this.q);
```

Seems like you could also just iterate with a for-each loop.

---

Few other things:

- Your code in `main` where you create the GUI needs to be wrapped inside a call to `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`:

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              // create the GUI here
          }
      });
  }
  ```

  This is because Swing is single-threaded and not thread-safe. See [*Initial Threads*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).
- You should call `super.paintComponent`, which paints the `JPanel` (background color, etc.):

  ```
  @Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
  ```
- As shown in the previous code snippet, `paintComponent` is a `protected` method and there's no reason to make it `public`.
- You shouldn't use `setSize` on a `JFrame`. If you want the frame to be a fixed size, you should override `getPreferredSize()` on the `JPanel`, then call `pack()` on the frame. The frame will size itself automatically around the panel inside it. (Example shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31014023/2891664).) The size of a `JFrame` includes e.g. title bar and borders so using `setSize` probably also interferes with your painting coordinates.